# _ctypes.COMError: (-2147220991, 'An event was unable to invoke any of the subscribers', (None, None, None, 0, None))

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am getting the following error while printing the control identifiers. Not sure how to fix this issue? Could someone help me please?

**App:** Windows store app (React Native and webview)

**Code:**

```
app = Application(backend='uia').start(
    r"powershell.exe /c start AppName",
    create_new_console=True,
    wait_for_idle=False)
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title_re=".*App Title*.", found_index=0, timeout=10).AppName

print(app.print_control_identifiers())
```

**Object Identifiers followed with errors:-**

```
 | ComboBox - 'Test'    (L2771, T247, R2871, B268)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['ComboBox', 'test', 'testComboBox', 'ComboBox0', 'ComboBox1']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="Test", control_type="ComboBox")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ComboBox - 'testing'    (L2875, T247, R2975, B268)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['testing', 'ComboBox2', 'TestingComboBox']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="tesing", control_type="ComboBox")
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | 
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | Static - '('    (L2978, T251, R2981, B264)
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | ['(Static', '(', 'Static56']
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | child_window(title="(", control_type="Text")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo\boo\test.py", line 96, in <module>
    print(test.getcontrolidentifiers())
  File "foo\boo\test.py", line 57, in getcontrolidentifiers
    return self.app.print_control_identifiers()
  File "foo\boo\\application.py", line 689, in print_control_identifiers
    print_identifiers([this_ctrl, ])
  File "foo\boo\\application.py", line 685, in print_identifiers
    print_identifiers(ctrl.children(), current_depth + 1, log_func)
  File "foo\boo\\application.py", line 685, in print_identifiers
    print_identifiers(ctrl.children(), current_depth + 1, log_func)
  File "foo\boo\\application.py", line 685, in print_identifiers
    print_identifiers(ctrl.children(), current_depth + 1, log_func)
  [Previous line repeated 7 more times]
  File "foo\boo\\application.py", line 641, in print_identifiers
    ctrl_id = all_ctrls.index(ctrl)
  File "foo\boo\\base_wrapper.py", line 662, in __eq__
    return self.element_info == other.element_info
  File "foo\boo\\uia_element_info.py", line 360, in __eq__
    return bool(IUIA().iuia.CompareElements(self.element, other.element))
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147220991, 'An event was unable to invoke any of the subscribers', (None, None, None, 0, None))
```

Comment: It looks like some element was disappeared during `dump_tree` call (alias of `print_control_identifiers`). I'd recommend to handle lazy initialization by `app.wait_cpu_usage_lower()` before dumping the tree.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov: Issue exists. The problem is that, it is not able to recognize the dynamic value. For example: Timer in the screen print above.

Comment: Looks like it is part of issue https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/949 I'm going to fix it.